# Pandas Series Calculation

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, series

My column (faq_helpful) have values **either** 0,1 or blanks. If it is blank, i wont bother about it. I want to find how many 0 and 1 are there but apparently, its returning the same value for both which is wrong.

```
for question, question_df in df_raw.groupby(['faq_question']): 
            count_0 = question_df['faq_helpful'].isin([0]).count()
            print(count_0)  # returns 25
            count_1 = question_df['faq_helpful'].isin([1]).count()
            print(count_1)   # also return 25 which is wrong
            total = count_0 + count_1
```

Comment: could you give a minimal code example of your dataframe, so that we can test is and find a solution?

Comment: Have you tried using ```df_raw.value_counts()```  from [pandas.Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on your code:

```
count = []
for question, question_df in df_raw.groupby(['faq_question']):
    count.append(len(question_df['faq_question']))
print(count)
[6, 9] # numbers based on my example 

total = sum(count)
print(total)
15
```

Pandas has an in-built function to count values in a Series, `pandas.Series.value_counts()`, [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). This function will sort and count all values in a Series. It returns a series, with the index indicating the counted value (in your case 0 and 1) and as its value the number of occurrences of it.

```
k = df_raw['faq_question'].value_counts()

print(k)
1.0    9
0.0    6
Name: faq_question, dtype: int64

total = sum(k)
```

Example code that was used to generate the above example, including 0/1/nan in the relevant column:

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [0,0,1,1,0,1,float("NaN"),0,1,1,1,1,0,0,float("NaN"),1,1],
    [9,4,float("NaN"),4,9,4,0,5,2,2,5,5,2,5,8,float("NaN"),1]]).T, 
    columns=["faq_question","other"])
```